# MySQL Query - Count Number of Records that Don't Reference Themselves

Tags: mysql, sql, self-reference

I'm still trying to use my limited knowledge of MySQL to help out a team at work, as in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105654/mysql-query-sum-the-capacity-of-multiple-warehouses).

The Warehouse table has a foreign key called nearest, which relates to another WarehouseID. What query generates a list of Warehouse records that are not referenced in any other Warehouse foreign key?

So running the query on:

```
ID    NEAREST
1     3
2     3
3     2
4     NULL
```

Would return:

```
ID
1
4
```

That might not seem a very useful query, but I've been trying to learn LEFT OUTER JOINs (which I'm fairly sure I need) and if I can manage this query I can easily apply it to the other tasks that are a bit harder for me to explain here.

I hope this is clear!

Comment: You can find various ways of accomplishing this in [my answer to another, similar, question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103889/not-getting-expected-result-while-joining/8104784#8104784 "not getting expected result while joining").

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM YourTable t1
LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 on t1.ID = T2.Nearest
WHERE t2.ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT NEAREST
                 FROM YourTable);
```